# Cannot understand getter/setter with object

Tags: objective-c, setter, conceptual, getter

It is easy to understand the concept of setter/getter for a simple data, an NSInteger for example.

If we say: NSInteger a;

The setter for "a" changes the value of a, and the getter only gets (returns) its value. It is then easy to understand atomic/nonantomic concept since atomic will guarantee that reading "a" when a is being chnaged will always return a whole value (getter and setter are synchronized).

But what I do not clearly understand is setter and getter for properties which are pointers to objects (NSData*, NSString* for example). Let's say for example a NSMutableData:

If we say: NSMutableData *m_my_mutable;

Imagine I have a setter setMyMutable and getMyMutable for this property which belongs to my object MyObject. If I do this, then I will call the getter (since I get the object before appending data):

[[MyObject getMyMutable] appendData....]

but appendingData will also modify it, thus sould not it be seen as a setter action instead ? Or does setter only refer to the fact of initiliazing a value (which can be retained for example).

There is something I must be missing in the concept.

Thanks
Apple92

Answer (score 2):

A setter sets the value of a property. When you set an integer property, a new integer value is stored. When you set an object property, a new object is stored. `appendData:` does not change the property — it changes **the data object itself**. An atomic property will only ensure that the property holds some complete value or another — it doesn't affect what you do with the object inside the property.

Incidentally, having mutable state (such as an NSMutableData object) that's accessible outside the owning object is almost always a bad idea. Once you do that, it becomes way too easy to have multiple objects all trying to make their own changes and stomping over each other.

Answer (score 0):

Setting does indeed only refer to initialization. This is why atomicity is not enough to ensure that mutable data structures are thread-safe. Instead, the guarantee you get is that the object will only be replaced or read in one fell swoop, so you don't end up with partial assignments.